# Galaxy S3 webview image broken

Tags: webview

A large image is broken.
I am using Galaxy S3.
Target = 4.4.4

No problem for other models.

My setting:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new mainWebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new TestWebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://www.amazon.com" );
```

I am using:

```
getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

Any solutions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should try to change the software render mode.

webView.setLayerType( View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null );

Answer (score 0):

You should use `webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);`
If set true, WebView will block image.